# Why Object.hashCode() does not follow Java code convention

Tags: java, hashcode, coding-style

Is there any specific reason, why hashCode is the only public method of Object class which does not follow Java Code Conventions recommended by Sun and later on by Oracle? I mean they could name it toHashCode() or getHashCode() or createHashCode() right?

EDIT:
I talk about Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language ( oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html ). These conventions are referenced in Oracle's book 'OCA Java SE 7 Programmer I Study Guide (Exam 1Z0-803) (Oracle Press) - Liguori, Robert'

In the [document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) we can read as follows:
"Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with
the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of
each internal word capitalized.".

AFAIK hashcode is not a verb.

Comment: I think those who wrote it can answer it? And, there is no such thing like we should prefix method name with `get` or `to` or `create`. Correct me if there is something like this out there.

Comment: Probably because the hashCode() method came before the conventions were published and by then it was too late to rename the method

Comment: I have a collection of examples where these "conventions" are ignored, and this `Collection` has a large `size()`.

Comment: I don't see which strict convention hashCode() breaks. It's camelCased like all methods should be. Methods often are verbs, but it's far from being a strict convention. String has length(). Enum (Java 5) has name(). Stream (Java 8) has min() and max().

Comment: Lucky for us, Java doesn't follow to the letter the brain-dead convention to shove a verb into each method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it *does* follow conventions.  It all depends on *which convention* you're talking about.

The OP is specifically interested in the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), and the conventions for method names are covered in [chapter 9](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).  First, it should be noted that this document is no longer maintained, and contains a large caveat:

> ... the information itself may no longer be valid. The last revision to this document was made on April 20, 1999

Of course, the `hashCode()` method predates 1999 so we *can* refer to the document to see if the method in question violated the conventions at the time.  The document states:

> Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

With regard to `hashCode()`, there is no disputing that it is *mixed case with the first letter lowercase*.  However, the OP seems to be of the opinion that it violates the convention that *methods should be verbs*; the implied assumption is that "hash code" or "hashcode" is a noun.

Before passing judgment, let's look at the third part of the convention: *the first letter of **each internal word** [is] capitalized*.  If you briefly assume that the original authors followed these conventions, then the capitalization of `hashCode()` indicates that its authors considered "hash" and "code" to be *separate* words.  If you treat them separately, the word "hash" *is a verb* in English.  With that interpretation, all parts of the convention are met.

Admittedly, the term "hash code" has become common jargon among (at least) Java developers and is often treated as a noun -- probably in no small part due to the name of this method in the first place.  (Chicken v. egg?)  But only the original authors can speak to their *intent*.

---

In my original answer, I used the [JavaBeans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/index.html) conventions as an example:

> A bean is a Java class with method names that follow the JavaBeans guidelines. A bean builder tool uses introspection to examine the bean class. Based on this inspection, the bean builder tool can figure out the bean's properties, methods, and events.

In JavaBeans, properties are accessed via a "getter" method, i.e. the "foo" property is read by calling `getFoo()`.  However, **the `hashCode()` method is a *technical requirement* imposed by the Java language** on all subclasses of `Object` but is *not generally a property* of the "business logic" that the object represents.  If you write a class to represent fruits, it would have properties like `getColor()`, `isSkinEdible()`, etc.  If not for Java's *technical requirement*, you would probably not consider writing a method like `getHashCode()` because... have you ever found a real, live banana with a hash code?

If `hashCode()` were named `getHashCode()` then, for this convention, JavaBeans would have to special-case it in order to ignore it.  Or it would always inspect that "property" for what commonly has little use in the main logic of your program.

---

I can't cover all possible conventions in this answer, but I have these thoughts on the other examples given in the question:

- `createHashCode()` - I would not use this, even by convention, because `hashCode()` returns an `int` (a primitive) and they're not *created* like reference types (Objects) are.  I think this would be the wrong verb.
- `toHashCode()` - To me, this represents a conversion.  But that's not what `hashCode()` does.  If `foo.hashCode()` returns `42` I should have no expectation that `42` is in any way a representation `foo`.  It was computed from information *about* the `foo` instance, but there's no other real correlation.  Plenty of other instances (of many classes) could return `42` so it's not a stand-in or analogue for any of them.

Comment: good point. Deserved +1

Comment: I talk about Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language ( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html ). These conventions are referenced in Oracle's book 'OCA Java SE 7 Programmer I Study Guide (Exam 1Z0-803) (Oracle Press) - Liguori, Robert'

Comment: @kukis Updated my answer to address that specific document.  I still think it fits the conventions well enough.

Comment: I would say close enough. Thanks for explenation.

Answer (score 5):

The [`hashCode()`](http://web.mit.edu/java_v1.0.2/www/javadoc/java.lang.Object.html#hashCode%28%29) method was specified before there were conventions.

Also, the convention is for naming Java Bean "properties," to facilitate wiring together beans in a design tool and assist in other forms of automation. It's unlikely that you'd need the hash code to be exposed as a property in these situations. In fact, because `getClass()` does follow Java Bean naming conventions, it requires a special case in many such tools to exclude it from the list of object properties.

Comment: sorry I didn't read carefully the question.

Comment: @Alboz There's only one question, why is it named as it is? But it's public because it needs to be invoked from another package (`java.util` and others). If it weren't `public`, it would be inaccessible.

Comment: If `class` wasn't a Java keyword, you can bet the method would be named `class()`.

Comment: @erickson my fault.. +1 for you, (i thought it was a question )